# Insert into two tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crud

I have a register form, in that form user can select whether they are **Farmer** or **Buyer** from a dropdown list. If the user select **Farmer** then I want to add the newly created `user_id` to the **farmer** table. If the user select **Buyer** then I want to add the newly created `user_id` to the **buyer** table.

But the behaviour now is when the user select **Buyer** from the dropdown list. The newly created `user_id` is saved on the **farmer** table instead of the **buyer** table.

How do I save the newly created `user_id` to the corresponding table?

Below are my code:

```
$user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'group' => $data['group'], 
]);

$farmer = Farmer::make([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
]);

$user->farmer()->save($farmer);
return $user;
```

Comment: Where is the logic for adding to the buyers table? In the code you've provided there aren't any checks to see whether the user is a farmer or a buyer so the row will always get added to the farmers table. Is there more to your code where you do check the request to see if they are a farmer or a buyer? If so, please can you add that to your question.

Comment: I have that logic in middleware to redirect each role to their own page, sorry for database I have no idea how to check each role..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*do like this.*

```
$decide = $data['select_option'];
if($decide == 'farmer'){
    $farmer = Farmer::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);
}
elseif($decide == 'buyer'){

    $buyer = Buyer::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple issues:

First, you are not using the check you described;

> there is select form that decide if user is farmer or buyer

Second, you are just creating a farmer, nothing to do with the buyer you described

> if the user is buyer, then buyer table get his/her user_id

Solution, is you need to first utilize the check, then create those table entries appropriately.

Also, please wrap your code in a transaction:

```
DB::transaction(function(){
    // Your code here...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for help me, I found the easiest way to solve my issues with this below :

```
if ($user->group == 2) {
        $buyer = Buyer::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);
    }elseif ($user->group == 3) {
        $farmer= Farmer::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);
    }

    $user->save();

    return $user;
```